# cap deployment is failing with "LoadError: cannot load such file -- sidekiq/capistrano"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, sidekiq, capistrano3, ruby-on-rails-4.1

While upgrading the app's rails version to 4.1, I have upgraded all gems with "bundle update"

But after upgrading, my Capistrano script was failing with the following error,

```
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sidekiq/capistrano
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With "bundle update", sidekiq gem also get updated to 3.0.0

In sidekiq 3.0.0, [capistrano integrated support has been removed](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment).

Instead, we can use **capistrano-sidekiq gem**.
Add gem into Gemfile and do bundle install

```
gem "capistrano-sidekiq"
```

and replace "`require 'sidekiq/capistrano'`" in **Capfile** with

```
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'
```

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem when I ran `cap production deploy`

My solution:

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```